# How calculate probability when we have continuous features?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

Suppose that we have a dataset with four features and each feature follows different distribution (normal,beta,gamma...). All features are continuous. So, how we can calculate the probability of any target if we want to follow Bayesian rule? ( Because the probability will be zero for each)

Comment: You mean the probability of an event (say the face of a coin you flip), given the values of the features? If you can write explicitly the probability in which you are interested, even better!

Comment: Yes,but instead I mean the continuous distro not discrete ones like toss a acoin. Suppose that in iris dataset we are going to determine the type of iris with Bayesian,but all features are continuous.

Comment: You should use probability of range of values instead of single value in a continuous domain. Ie in [0,1] each x has zero probability but a range [x1,x2]  has non-zero probability